How to get full list of tables if count is big in the adf web activity?
We have 18,000 tables in the Table Storage Account.
I have created a web activity to list the tables in the storage account:

Web Activity - ListTables
URL: @concat('https://stccuatuks001.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list', pipeline().parameters.sourceSAS)
Headers: Accept-application/json # Add as dynamic content value
Method: GET

sourceSAS is the storage account SAS token generated for table storage service and this value is given in the pipeline parameters.
I have run the pipeline where I'm getting only list of 1st 1000 tables, not more than that.
How do I get complete 18,000 list of table names in the output from the web activity or do I need to add any additional steps/configuration for it?

The api returns a continuation token in the x-ms-continuation-NextTableName header. You'll have to take that and pass it as a query string parameter NextTableName into subsequent requests untill all tables are retrieved and no more continuation token is returned.

Yes i have received that x-ms-continuation-NextTableName and its value in the output of web activity but where I should pass that header? Is it in the same web activity - headers section?

Call the same URL but add the value of it the querystring &NextTableName=example. So for 18,000 tables you have to make 18 REST requests total (since 1000 is the max retrieved).

I did not understood what you are saying

To list more than 1000 tables through ADF, you can follow the procedure below:
After running the web activity, save the x-ms-continuation-NextTableName header value. Add a SetVariable activity with the continuation variable to save the value with the dynamic expression in SetVariable: @activity('Web1').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['x-ms-continuation-NextTableName'], as shown below:

Add an Until activity to the SetVariable activity with the expression @equals(coalesce(variables('continution'),'cs'),'cs'). Inside the Until activity, add the following activities:
Add a web activity with the same URL used in the first web activity, but with &NextTableName=<variable> added, as shown below:
@concat('https://stccuatuks001.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list','&NextTableName=',variables('continution'), pipeline().parameters.sourceSAS)

Add an Append Variable activity with an array variable list and the dynamic expression @activity('Web2').output.value, as shown below:

Add a SetVariable activity with the continuation variable and the dynamic expression @activity('Web2').output.ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders['x-ms-continuation-NextTableName'].
After the Until activity is complete, you will have a list of all table names in the list variable.
For more information, you can refer to a similar question in Q&A.

Thank you. Please give us some time - we will get back you in hours.

Apologies. This will take time to check this solution from our end.
